# How to prepolulate the combobox list from Excel into userform?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to take a "list of name" data sets from excel and use it for an Combobox Userform. The user uses a dropdown menu from the Combobox to make his/her selection of a name.

My problem is that I don't know how to apply the "list of name" data sets to the combobox. The range for the list of names is in cell C2:AU2 and its in a worksheet called "DoNotPrint-Names". Once the name is chosen by the user I want it to output it to a cell in "DoNotPrint-Setup" worksheet when the button "Next" is clicked.

---

Screenshot Part of the Names list:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KneaD.jpg

---

Screenshot of Userform:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6FGL.jpg

I tried the code below which asks the Userform to prepopulate cells from "DoNotPrint - Names" worksheet by transposing it first since its a single row. Not sure how to proceed afterward.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ComboBox1.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(DoNotPrint - Names.Range("C2:AU2"))

End Sub
```

Comment: load ur list on `UserForm_activate()` using  `For Each Variant in YourList` if its dynamic range, `Me.ComboBox1.addItems variant`

Comment: @0m3r Can u show me an example of what u mean? I am new to Userforms. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Select your list and give it name,*

*Example*

[image]

*Then load that list on your `ComboBox1`*

*Code Example*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim vList As Variant

    For Each vList In [MyList]
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem vList
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: *A simple one liner:* `Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose([myList])` :-)

Comment: Cool- post aa answer @T.M.

Answer (score 1):

**Addendum to found solution**

Just in Addition to @0m3r 's *valid answer*, you can use the *array Approach* to assign the entire named horizontal list to the comboboxe's `.List` property in a one liner:

```
Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose([myList])
```

**Edit**

Alternatively you can use the control's `.Column` property which seems to be rather unknown:

```
Me.ComboBox1.Column = [myList].Value
```